# ActionBar background using appCompat does not showing

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar-compat

I have:

Background: http://pastebin.com/Un6FQG98

Style whith theme calling background: http://pastebin.com/SNtBJr8N

AndroidManifest calling theme: http://pastebin.com/v4QmUbVt

And activity extends ActionBarActivity.

apparently everything is correct and yet not appear the background.
when setted via java code, it works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support higher APIs as well as older ones you need to also use `android:`:

```
<style name="Theme.Actionbarlogin" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Actionbarlogin</item>
    <!--Support older APIs-->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Actionbarlogin</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Actionbarlogin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/teste_icon_large</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|homeAsUp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_login</item>
    <!--Support older APIs-->
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_background_login</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/teste_icon_large</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|homeAsUp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried to do as you said and still did not work. I am testing with the api 19
my new style: http://pastebin.com/hcgtcnxE

Comment: i change the parente to:  <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Actionbarlogin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar"> and worked